# How to pass Django DateTimeField inside POST method of contact form

Tags: python, django

I create an contact-form using Django models. I added DateTimeField in my models.py file so that I can see the date-time when the contact-form was submitted. After added DateTimeField in my models.py.

I am getting this error when clicking submit button of contact-form:

```
 ['“” value has an invalid format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ] format.']
```

I run **makemigrations** and **migrate** after adding the DateTimeField in models.py and didn't get any error massage while running makemigrations and migrate.

```
>>python manage.py makemigrations
No changes detected
>> python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
```

#my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
import datetime
# Create your models here.
class Contact(models.Model):
    current_time = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,default=datetime.date.today)
    name =models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email =models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
```

#my forms.py file

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from .models import Contact

class ContactForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
      model = Contact
      fields = ['name','email','message',]
     

def clean(self):
       # data from the form is fetched using super function
    super(ContactForm, self).clean()
         
    # extract the username and text field from the data
    name = self.cleaned_data.get('name')
  
    if len(name) < 5:
        self._errors['username'] = self.error_class([
                'Minimum 5 characters required'])
    
    
    return self.cleaned_data
```

#my views.py file

```
def home_view(request,*args,**kwargs):
    print(args,kwargs)
    print(request.user)
    #return HttpResponse("<h1>hello world</h1>")
    if request.method == "POST":
      contact = ContactForm(request.POST)
      if contact.is_valid():  
        post = contact.save(commit = False)
        post.save()
        
    fm = ContactForm()
    context= {'form':fm}
    return render(request, 'index.html',context)
```

how can I pass the DateTimeField in post method of my contact-form??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `datetime.date.today()` methods returns `datetime.date(2021, 3, 26)` which gives current year, month, date. The django models.DateTimeField() requires the input to be in this `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM[:ss[.uuuuuu]][TZ]` format.

Change `models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,default=datetime.date.today)` to `models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,default=datetime.datetime.now)` or `from django.utils import timezone` then `models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True,default=timezone.now)`